# onhover how to get the image width and height using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am displaying in my webpage a number of images within a div the div and images are created dynamically with a looping.

**I need to get the width and height of the each image by using the jquery without using id like this**

```
 document.getElementById('Image/div id');
```

because there will a lot of images dynamically created by the loop depend upon the conditions
so, is there any way to get the height and width of the image when user hover/click the image

I struck with this for a long and been here finally hopes i get a solution

Comment: does this apply to all images? or just a subset of images?

Comment: Which version of jQuery? Also can you post a skeleton structure of the rendered html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use jQuery `on()` to attach a handler to the *nearest common parent container*. that way, you can at least control which subset of images you want this function to take effect.

```
$('#container').on('mouseover','img',function(){
    var width = $(this).width();
    var height = $(this).height();
});
```

like:

```
<div>
    <img> //will not affect this one since it's not under "#container"
</div>
<div id="container">
   <img> //the handler affects this one
   <div>
      <img> //the handler also affects this one
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest, if you want to show this information on the page:

```
$('img').hover(
    function(){
        var h = $(this).height(),
            w = $(this).width();
        $('<div />').insertAfter($(this)).text('height: ' + h + '; width: ' + w +'.');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).next('div').remove();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uReTm/).

---

**Almost pointless edit** to make it a little bit prettier by reducing the calls to `$(this)` and coupling it to some CSS:

```
$('img').hover(
    function(){
        var that = $(this),
            h = that.height(),
            w = that.width();
        $('<div />')
            .css('width',w)
            .text('height: ' + h + '; width: ' + w +'.')
            .insertAfter(that);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).next('div').remove();
    });​
```

CSS:

```
div {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

div > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: #f90;
    background-color: #000;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

​
[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uReTm/1/).

---

**Edited** because jQuery's not really necessary for this effect (albeit it does simplify the implementation), so: a plain JavaScript alternative:

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i=0,len=img.length;i<len;i++){
    img[i].onmouseover = function(){
        var that = this,
            h = that.offsetHeight,
            w = that.offsetWidth,
            p = that.parentNode,
            d = document.createElement('div');
        d.style.width = w + 'px';
        d.textContent = 'Width: ' + w + '; height: ' + h + '.';
        p.appendChild(d);

    };
    img[i].onmouseout = function(){
        var that = this;
        that.parentNode.removeChild(that.nextSibling);
    };
}​
```

​
[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uReTm/2/).

---

**Final edit (I think)**, because I couldn't remember the compatibility for `node.textContent`, I thought this amendment might aid compatibility with lower versions of IE (using `document.createTextNode()` instead of relying on `node.textContent`/`node.innerText` and so on...):

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i=0,len=img.length;i<len;i++){
    img[i].onmouseover = function(){
        var that = this,
            h = that.offsetHeight,
            w = that.offsetWidth,
            p = that.parentNode,
            d = document.createElement('div'),
            text = document.createTextNode('Width: ' + w + '; height: ' + h + '.');
        d.appendChild(text);
        d.style.width = w + 'px';
        p.appendChild(d);

    };
    img[i].onmouseout = function(){
        var that = this;
        that.parentNode.removeChild(that.nextSibling);
    };
}​
```

​
[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uReTm/3/).

While I don't have IE 7, or lower, the above does work in IE 8 at least. If anyone has comments about functionality in IE 6 or 7 I'd be interested..!

References:

- 'Plain' JavaScript:

  - [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
  - [`document.createTextNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createTextNode).
  - [`element.offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetHeight).
  - [`element.offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetWidth).
  - [`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style).
  - [`node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/node.appendChild).
  - [`node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.parentNode).
  - [`node.removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/node.removeChild).
  - [`node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/node.textContent).
- jQuery:

  - [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/).
  - [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).
  - [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).
  - [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
  - [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
  - [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

Comment: :the stuffs here is useful a bunch... and it works good in IE6 and IE7

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your issue?

```
$('img').hover(function() {
  console.log($(this).width());
  console.log($(this).height());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)` to refer to the image being hovered.

```
$("#div_id").hover(function(){
  alert("H:" + $(this).height() + " W:" + $(this).width() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".img").mouseover(function() {

    var $div = $(this);
    var $item = $div.find("img");

    var width = $item.width();
    var height = $item.height();
}
```

try this.